# How to 'Reset' my OS X Ruby on Rails Gems?

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I've been playing with various development tools related to Ruby on Rails on OS X Lion, and things are kind of hosed up. I'd like to remove all my gems and re-install them. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use the [Ruby Version Manager](http://beginrescueend.com/) and not have to remove and reinstall all gems.

From the site: 
"RVM is a command-line tool which allows you to easily install, manage, and work with multiple ruby environments from interpreters to sets of gems."